# Can't get Chrome Extension to store settings via popup.html & popup.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to setup a Chrome Extension, so when the user clicks on the extension icon, it presents two checkboxes that the user can check or not (via popup.html). This works. Then, I want the user to click on a Save button, and have popup.js fire, which will store their choices in chrome storage. I cannot get this to work at all.  I can't get anything to show up in console.log either.

Ultimately, I want my code to check to see if anything has been set in storage, retrieve the values and pre-set them, and then have the choices show to the user.  If they change something, I want to establish a listener that notes the change, and saves the current settings to storage.  But I need to walk before I run.

I should point out that I am a neophyte web developer and have done my best searching the web, looking at code examples, etc. for weeks to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Here are my key files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "WSH",
  "description": "WSH Description",
  "version": "2.7.3",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "icon-32.png"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "*://*.boardgamegeek.com/*"
    ],
    "js": [
      "content.js"
    ],
    "css": [
      "content.css"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_idle"
  }],
  "permissions" : [
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/*",
    "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "32": "icon-32.png",
      "48": "icon-48.png",
      "128": "icon-128.png"
    },
  "default_title": "Click for GCV Options",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
/* The container */
.container {
  width: 125px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
</style>
<body>
<h1>GCV Objects</h1>
<label class="container">Cards
  <input type="checkbox" id="GCVCards" name="GCVCards" value="1" checked>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Tokens
  <input type="checkbox" id="GCVTokens" name="GCVTokens" value="1" checked>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<input id="Save" type="submit" name="Save" value="Save">
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function save_options(){
  var GCVCards = document.getElementById('GCVCards').value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'GCVCards': GCVCards}, function() {
    console.log('GCVCards Value is set to: ' + GCVCards);
  });
}

document.getElementById('Save').onclick = save_options;
```

Comment: do you get  to the save_option function?, put a console message in the start of save

Comment: I have done so.  It never gets there.  As I said, I don't know why.

Comment: i saw somewhere, move js into head tag, before body. you code look fine and should work, try cache clean and restart chrome

Comment: Putting it in the <head> made no difference.  All the examples I have seen are in the <body> right before the </body> with the reasoning being that it is read top to bottom.  Again, I am no expert, so what do I know.  I tried inside <head>, but as I stated, this accomplished nothing (no behavioral difference).  It never makes it to popup.js for some reason.

Comment: remove link from permission, and then remove matches liink also. try aain, you can also view errors in extension tab. and i tried your code, it works, but without content_scripts and permision of githubusercontent

Comment: While I do appreciate your help, unfortunately, both of those have to be in there, otherwise there is no extension. There would be no point to this work at all without content scripts and permission of the githubusercontent, so this is most definitely not the answer.